# Button with right arrow - transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-shapes, css-transforms

I've made css button with right border in arrow shape, with the help of css transforms and pseudo elements. Now I'm trying to add transition to background on hover but realized there is a problem, in the place where button is overlapped by pseudo element, during transition color is different. See it below, try to hover the button:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
linear-gradient(150deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
linear-gradient(30deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
linear-gradient(150deg, #445 12%, transparent 12.5%, transparent 87%, #445 87.5%, #445),
linear-gradient(60deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a), 
linear-gradient(60deg, #99a 25%, transparent 25.5%, transparent 75%, #99a 75%, #99a);
background-size:80px 140px;
background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 40px 70px, 40px 70px, 0 0, 40px 70px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.more-skewed {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid 2px white;
  border-right: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.more-skewed:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: 50%;
  border-right: solid 2px white;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
  width: 15px;
  background: inherit;
}

.more-skewed:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  bottom: -2px;
  top: 50%;
  border-right: solid 2px white;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  width: 15px;
  background: inherit;
}

.more-skewed:hover {
  color: black;
 background: white;
}
```

```html
<a class="more-skewed" href="#">MORE</a>
```

Is it possible to resolve this? JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/k9jhuc34/ 
(Button is initially transparent, and it is over image background.)

Comment: Use Bootstrap, Things get easy and responsive by using bootstrap.

Comment: Check this Url : http://codecanyon.net/item/pure-css-buttons-with-arrow/full_screen_preview/6363840 hope it help :)

Comment: It is kind of a known problem because (roughly speaking) you are putting a semi-transparent white on top of another semi-transparent white during the transition and so naturally the overlapping area will appear whiter. You can do something like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L71cmjms/) but as you would see the hover area (or the hit area) is not exactly within the shape on the right side.

Comment: @Harry Thanks, I like this solution :) Hover area is rectangle... But i think it is better than that weird figure during transition! If you will post it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @SunilGehlot thanks... There is used solid background, I need transparent background :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in my comment, this is kind of expected because roughly speaking what happens is that a semi-transparent white layer is being placed on top of another such layer in the areas where there is an overlap and so, that area quickly appears whiter than the rest.

**Using Skew Transform:**

One solution would be like in the below snippet but it makes the hover/hit area a rectangle. What I've done here is to make the pseudo-elements create the entire shape (other than the left border) and a `overflow-hidden` on the parent prevents the unwanted skewed portions on left side from showing up.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.more-skewed {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-left: solid 2px white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.more-skewed:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 50%;
  border-right: solid 2px white;
  border-top: solid 2px white;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  z-index: -1;
}
.more-skewed:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  border-right: solid 2px white;
  border-bottom: solid 2px white;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  z-index: -1;
}
.more-skewed:hover {
  color: black;
}
.more-skewed:hover:before,
.more-skewed:hover:after {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<a class="more-skewed" href="#">MORE</a>
```

---

**Using Rotate with Perspective:**

Another solution could be to use rotate transforms with a bit of perspective added to it. By setting the appropriate value for `transform-origin` we can make it produce a trapezoid which can be placed at the appropriate positions to produce an arrow. Here, the hover/hit area remains within the shape  but this approach is useful only if the text is small and static. If the text becomes longer, the slope on the right side of the shape becomes more gradual instead of being steep (of-course, we can change the transforms to make it look better, but it is not very useful if we have to keep changing it often).

```css
.more-skewed {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid 2px white;
  border-right: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 16px 40px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.more-skewed:before,
.more-skewed:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid white;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.more-skewed:before {
  top: -2px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
}
.more-skewed:after {
  bottom: -2px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-30deg);
}
.more-skewed:hover {
  color: black;
}
.more-skewed:hover:before,
.more-skewed:hover:after {
  background: white;
}
.more-skewed span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
body {
  background: gray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<a class="more-skewed" href="#">
  <span>MORE</span>
</a>
<br/>
<a class="more-skewed" href="#">
  <span>MORE LONGER TEXT</span>
</a>
```

(*Feedback is that the above snippet breaks in IE. I will address that when I find time.*)

---

Here is another version that I came up with as I was playing around. It is a bit like a background slide-fill effect which keeps the hover/hit area within the shape but due to the way gradients are rendered by browsers, it isn't very clean. Thought of leaving it here just in-case you find it useful.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.more-skewed {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid 2px white;
  border-right: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  background: linear-gradient(245deg, transparent 9px, white 10px), linear-gradient(295deg, transparent 9px, white 10px);
  background-size: 0% 50%;
  background-position: top right, bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.more-skewed:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -7px;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: skewX(25deg);
  width: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white);
  background-size: 3px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
  transition: all 1s 1s linear;
}
.more-skewed:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -7px;
  bottom: -2px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
  width: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(white, white);
  background-size: 3px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
  transition: all 1s 1s linear;
}
.more-skewed:hover {
  color: black;
  background-size: 100% 50%;
  transition: all 1s 1s linear;
}
.more-skewed:hover:before,
.more-skewed:hover:after {
  color: black;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<a class="more-skewed" href="#">MORE</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! 2nd solution is smart but there is a very small semi-transparent line near right border. Even when I replaced gradient with box-shadow: https://jsfiddle.net/ahoc2Loc/1/ . I guess it's a bug caused by transform.

Comment: Actually it is the border and gradients @Julia. That is the rendering problem I mentioned in my answer. I will try and see if there is a way to address it.

Answer (score 1):

If the background the link is sitting on is just a solid colour as in the provided example, you could achieve this with a couple of triangles, like so:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;}
body{
    background:#333;
}
a{
    border:2px solid #fff;
    border-right:0;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    line-height:50px;
    padding:0 40px;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition:background 1s ease-out,color 1s ease-out;
}
a::before{
    border-top:27px solid transparent;
    border-left:14px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:27px solid transparent;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right:-14px;
    top:-2px;
}
a::after{
    border-top:25px solid transparent;
    border-left:12px solid #333;
    border-bottom:25px solid transparent;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right:-12px;
    top:0;
    transition:opacity 1s ease-out;
}
a:hover{
    background:#fff;
    color:#333;
}
a:hover::after{
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">More</a>
```

---

I also came up with the following, but it's a bit "janky" and the arrow isn't quite what you're looking for. I decided to edit it in anyway in case it's of use to anyone else in the future.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;}
body{
    background:#333;
}
a{
    border:2px solid #fff;
    border-right:0;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    line-height:50px;
    padding:0 40px;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition:background 1s ease-out,color 1s ease-out;
}
a::before{
    border-right:2px solid #fff;
    border-top:2px solid #fff;
    content:"";
    height:36px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-19px;
    top:6px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    width:36px;
}
a::after{
    background:linear-gradient(-135deg,#fff 50%,transparent 50%);
    content:"";
    height:34px;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    right:-17px;
    top:8px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    transition:opacity 1s ease-out;
    width:34px;
}
a:hover{
    background:#fff;
    color:#333;
}
a:hover::after{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">More</a>
```

Comment: Nope, it is on the image background :)

Comment: Can you update your question (and example, if possible) to include that information?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below arrow code with `transition`, hope it help.

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<a class="arrow_box">
MORE
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: gray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: gray;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color:#FFF;
  transition:0.4s;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
  transition:0.4s;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0);
    border-left-color: gray;
  border-width: 24px;
  margin-top: -24px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 26px;
  margin-top: -26px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.arrow_box:hover{
  color:#000;
  background:#FFF;
}
.arrow_box:hover:after{
  border-left-color: #FFF;
}
```

Check [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hg81fr0j/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but in the desired design button is initially transparent, only has white border, as it is placed over image background